# Input type ="number" Value does not update in html is this normal

Tags: javascript, input

I have not used this before just now and noticed it does not update its value in html?

Basically i have a Html Table with this in it , and user will update it to a quantity needed and Submit and i will take the Html parse it to get the things.

But in the html i see the value of input box is always 1, i it never updates itself

```
<input type="number" id="testNumber"   value="1" min="1" max="100" />
```

Comment: You need to write server-side code.

Comment: @SLaks under some circumstances what if i cant?

Comment: @Claies i meant the input field. Common..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While yes, the markup indicates that the value is still 1, if this form were to be submitted, the displayed value of the number input would still get returned.

You can verify this by running the following in your browser's console:

```
var input = document.getElementById('testNumber');
input.value;
```

**EDIT 1:**

If you want the value of the html to match the value of the dom element, assign it yourself, like so:

```
input.setAttribute('value', input.value);
```

Comment: Yes i have tested that but i need it to update in html.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a sample. But it handles the INCREASE(+)/DECREASE(-) buttons clicked and updates the input value.

```
$("input[type=number]").click(function(e) {

    $(this).attr( 'value', $(this).val() );

});
```

Comment: That's a good function, but I changed .click for .keyup as a user could or normally will use the tab key instead of clicking

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#input1').keyup(function(){
                   jQuery("#testNumber").val(jQuery(this).val());
                });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Change Value:
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1">
<br/>
<br/>
result
<input type="text" id="testNumber" value="1" min="1" max="100" readonly="" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood this question right, you need to change the `number input` on event.

here is you can try

`$("#quantity").val(1);`

on event it will change the `#quantity` to 1 even you would see this on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

My input had `type="number"` and I was setting a non numeric value to it using JavaScript. This is a really subtle mistake and hard to notice.

PS: Probably not an answer to the question above, but all my google searches returned this page as a first result.